Winsock Server Bind failed 10047
Server code
#pragma once
#include <WinSock2.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include<WS2tcpip.h>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

/*
struct sockaddr_in {
    unsigned short sin_port;
    unsigned short sin_family;
    struct in_addr sin_addr;
    char sin_zero[8];
};
*/

class Log {
    int OutputMessageLogLevel = 1; //will output to a .txt log file if its a warning or higher
    int LogLevel = 0; //0 will be generic print

    public:
    void SetLogLevel(int NewLogLevel) {
        LogLevel = NewLogLevel;
    }

    void print(std::string Message) {
        if (LogLevel == 0) {
            std::cout << Message << std::endl;
        }
        else
        {
            if (LogLevel == 1) {
                std::cout << "[Warning] " + Message << std::endl;
            }
            else
            {
                if (LogLevel == 2) {
                    std::cout << "[Error] " + Message << std::endl;
                }
            }
        }
    }
};

int main() {
    Log logger;

    SOCKET ServerSocket, AcceptSocket;
    int port = 55555;
    WSADATA wsaData;

    int wsaerr;
    WORD WindowsVersionRequested = MAKEWORD(2, 2);
    wsaerr = WSAStartup(WindowsVersionRequested, &wsaData);

    if (wsaerr != 0) {
        logger.print("The Winsock dll is not found ):");
        return wsaerr;
    }
    else
    {
        std::string WSAStatus = wsaData.szSystemStatus;
        logger.print("The Winsock dll is found (:");
        logger.print("Status: " + WSAStatus);
    }

    ServerSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
    ServerSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

    if (ServerSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        logger.print("Error at socket(): ");
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        logger.print("socket() is Good to go");
    }

    logger.print("Now binding server socket...");

    sockaddr_in service; //buffer to store numerical binary representation of the IP address. also see struct sockaddr_in above
    //The IP address is returned in network byte order.

    service.sin_family = AF_INET; //To use IPV4 configuration or whatever
    InetPton(AF_INET, _T("127.0.0.1"), &service); //127.0.0.1 will loop back to your own machine for local testing
    service.sin_port = htons(port); //port is 55555 the integer which we initialize up top
    
    if (bind(ServerSocket, (SOCKADDR*)&service, sizeof(service)) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        logger.print("bind() failed: ");
        std::cout << WSAGetLastError() << std::endl;
        closesocket(ServerSocket);
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        logger.print("bind() is okay,Success binding socket");
    }

    //int listen(SOCKET s, int backlog);

    if (listen(ServerSocket, 1) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        logger.print("Could not listen for Socket: " );
        return -1;
    }
    else
    {
        logger.print("Could not listen for Socket: " );
    }

    logger.print("Accepting Connections...");

    AcceptSocket = accept(ServerSocket, NULL, NULL);
    if (AcceptSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        logger.print("Accept Failed: ");
        return -1;
    } {
        logger.print("Accepted Connection!");
        system("pause");
        WSACleanup();
    }
    
};

Unlike the other post this got linked linked to, I have set the sockaddr_in.sin_family to AF_INET already.
Don't mind the random log class, that's because I was bored.
After creating a simple server following this tutorial I get a bind error. The tutorial is 2 years outdated which just so happened to be enough that when calling the InetPton(), there are two less parameters that are used. And here is the output:
The Winsock dll is found (:
Status: Running
socket() is Good
Now binding server socket...
bind() failed:
10047

I've tried googling a bunch of stuff and found the command "netsh winsock reset" which after using and restarting my computer did not change anything. Next I went to system32\drivers\etc\hosts or a path very similar to this and edited the hosts file to make sure that the local host loopback address was correct as I used it in my code. Someone else suggested completely reinstalling Winsock but I don't know how to do that and I don't know if my code is bad or whatnot yet.

You can use FormatMessage to print a meaningful message instead of a faceless error number.  Also, you forgot to set sin_addr.

For sin_addr I need the binary representation of the local host ip right? so how would I got about that?

nvm been looking around the Microsoft Docs a lot and found the struct for sin_addr with all of the super strange parts to it. Gotta love Microsoft

I haven't noticed you are calling InetPton. You are not doing it correctly. You need in_addr as an argument, not sockaddr_in. So just pass &service.sin_addr there and you don't need to know about the strange parts (which have little to do with Microsoft by the way).

Ahh I see thank you, but, I now get WSAEACCES when binding the socket. I changed the port a few times too and same issue and I'm pretty clueless right now

tried even more and it fixed it, I don't know how to mark solutions but I will figure it out and mark you soon. Thank you so much!!!

@Ethereal no answer was posted, so there is nothing to mark. And since the question was closed, you can't post your own answer, either

Thanks y’all I’ll be sure to post on here more often, it’s great
